# Retrieve/recover cert pfx from Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, powershell, ssl-certificate, pfx, azure-application-gateway

I want to retrieve/download the original pfx certificate that was uploaded onto our Application Gateway.

So far I have done the following in PowerShell:

```
$appGw = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name "appgatewayname" -ResourceGroupName "appgatewayresourcegroup"

$certs = Get-AzApplicationGatewaySslCertificate -ApplicationGateway $appGw

$certBase64 = $certs[0].PublicCertData
$certBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($certBase64)

[io.file]::WriteAllBytes("C:\directory\newcert.pfx", $certBytes)
```

However, it doesn't seem to be a valid certificate, especially when I try to upload it onto our KeyVault.

Is anyone familiar, and is this even possible? Should I use the Data property instead of the PublicCertData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.pfx file can't be retrieved after you uploaded it to an application gateway listener. I have checked [Azure resource explorer](https://resources.azure.com/), there is no API provided by Azure to retrieve it. And I also double-checked with the Azure product team.

Though seems we can use `Get-AzApplicationGatewaySslCertificate` PS command to get certs, but actually, it provides you with PublicCertData only, there is no PrivateCertData of .pfx file. I also have tested on my side, the value of Data property is empty.

So if you want to upload this .pfx file to Azure KV, I am afraid the only way is uploading the original pfx certificate to Azure KV directly.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. The Data property is definitely null.

Comment: @AnimaSola Thanks for your reply. So please mark this answer if your confusion has been solved, thanks!